# How to insert outlook actionable message from outlook Add-In

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, office365api, outlook-web-addins

New to outlook actionable message, From the documentation I can see that we can send a card via email or connector, is there any way we can send/insert card using addIn from email compose window (using api like Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setSelectedDataAsync())? 
Also Can we insert multiple actionable card in one mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently inserting actionable message via outlook add-in is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.